# Binding doesn't get called on code behind propertry

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

So I have a Grid with some checkboxes, etc inside it and wanted to set them all to readonly , I added the `IsEnabled` part below:

```
<Grid IsEnabled="{Binding IsFieldReadOny}">
```

And in the code behind added this:

```
Private _isFieldReadOnly As Boolean = True
Public Property IsFieldReadOny() As Boolean
    Get
        Return _isFieldReadOnly
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        _isFieldReadOnly = value
    End Set
End Property
```

But when I put breakpoint, it does not get hit or do anything. 
If I manually hard code a True for the grid, then it works. 
I am new to both `WPF` and `VB` syntax, so it might be something easy that I am not doing right.

Comment: There is a lot to WPF.  If you are doing the MVVM approach as I can only assume you may be you need to ensure that your View has it's 'datacontext' set to be the viewmodel where your property is.  Essentially you set a datacontext in the code behind like Me.DataContext = (yourviewmodel) or in other ways too.  You also need to worry about implementing INotifyPropertyChanged in your ViewModel should properties change later too.

Comment: The DataContext of the Grid (or one of its parent elements) must be set to an instance of the class that owns the IsFieldReadOnly property. Or you should explicitly specify the source object of the Binding. Besides that, the property must notify the Binding about a changed value, which is usually done by implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. Start reading here: [Data Binding Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Source part of a DataBinding doesn't have to be INotifyPropertyChanged, right?  Target must be

Comment: @Bohn No, the source must implement INPC. The target must be a dependency property.

Comment: @Clemens : The place that IsFieldReadOnly  is defined is code behind of the same XAML file that has the Grid on it.

Comment: @Bohn Nah, and it will work without that.  It is just if you have a propery of bar on class foo.  Class foo has to 'Implements INotifyPropertyChanged' below the class info.  I'm just saying if bool changes back and forth from true to false during the 'code' process of whatever the UI thread will not know about it unless that interface is implemented.

Comment: Along with what Clemens gave you there is an amazing tutorial Josh Smith wrote close to eight years ago on the whole design pattern of MVVM and how it works with a solution to play with: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx  I did a lot of my initial learning around this article and a lot of it is still very relative funny enough.

Comment: Then you could write the binding like `{Binding IsFieldReadOnly, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}`. Still you need to implement INPC, or make IsFieldReadOnly a dependency property (which provide their own change notification).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very simple example of MVVM and binding with one way out of TONS to do things.  Binding in and of itself has many many options of traversing a visual tree with 'RelativeSource' and scoping.  As well as mode options and other settings.  I chose to focus on keeping it simple though.  I just want a view that has a textbox, you can change yourself, a button you can hit, a label that will update from the text you changed.

So here is a basic view:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SimpleWPF"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
      <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}" Height="30" />
      <Button Content="Example" Command="{Binding DoCommand}" />
    <Label Content="{Binding Output}" Height="30" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

I want to set up a single helper class for a 'DelegateCommand'.  You can do this many ways but essentially I am saving repeat methods for later reuse for commands to help with an ICommand interface.

```
Public Class DelegateCommand(Of T)
  Implements ICommand
  Private _execute As Action(Of T)

  Public Sub New(execute As Action(Of T))
    _execute = execute
  End Sub

  Public Event CanExecuteChanged As EventHandler
  Private Event ICommand_CanExecuteChanged As EventHandler Implements ICommand.CanExecuteChanged

  Private Function ICommand_CanExecute(parameter As Object) As Boolean Implements ICommand.CanExecute
    Return True
  End Function

  Private Sub ICommand_Execute(parameter As Object) Implements ICommand.Execute
    _execute.Invoke(DirectCast(parameter, T))
  End Sub
End Class
```

Now in my Code behind of the view it should be pretty minimal except this:

```
Class MainWindow
  Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    Me.DataContext = New MainViewModel()
  End Sub

End Class
```

And my MainViewModel is pretty simple in this case is pretty simple and I am only implementing INotifyPropertyChanged.  I would usually do most of my stuff like this in a base class and inherit that on larger solutions.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class MainViewModel
  Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

  Private _text As String
  Public Property Text As String
    Get
      Return _text
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
      _text = value
      OnPropertyChanged(NameOf(Text))
    End Set
  End Property

  Private _output As String
  Public Property Output As String
    Get
      Return _output
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
      _output = value
      OnPropertyChanged(NameOf(Output))
    End Set
  End Property

  Public Sub New()
    _text = "Test"
  End Sub

  Public ReadOnly Property DoCommand As New DelegateCommand(Of Object)(AddressOf DoIt)

  Private Sub DoIt(obj As Object)
    Output = $"{Text} {DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString}"
  End Sub

#Region "Implement INotifyProperty Changed"
  Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

  Public Sub OnPropertyChanged(ByVal info As String)
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(info))
  End Sub
#End Region
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use a generic binding you are looking at the DataContext of the object and by generic I mean a {Binding PropertyName} without any other parameters.  In order to bind to a property within your code behind (which I don't recommend doing) then you need to tell the binding to look at that location. You also need to use a dependency property for binding on UIElements since it's already built in.

So to make this work I've named the Window the Grid is in 'window'.  Then I've given the binding expression a direct connection to the property.

```
 <Grid IsEnabled="{Binding IsReadOnlyField, ElementName=window}" />
```

I've then added a binding to the Checkbox as well to the same thing.

```
 <CheckBox Content="Is Grid Enabled" IsChecked="{Binding IsReadOnlyField, ElementName=window}" />
```

Then in the code behind I've changed the property to a DependencyProperty.

```
public bool IsReadOnlyField
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsReadOnlyFieldProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsReadOnlyFieldProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsReadOnlyFieldProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(IsReadOnlyField), typeof(bool), typeof(MainWindow));
```

This will get the binding working.

If you are not using the code behind and are binding to a ViewModel or any class you should preferably make that class interface INotifyPropertyChanged (although you can also make that ViewModel inherit from DependencyObject and use the same DependencyPropery... It's just normally used for UI elements).  Then write the property as normal and in the setter call the property changed event.  However, you will most likely set the binding back to the way you had it and just put that ViewModel as the DataContext.

There's A LOT to explain about binding as it can be very flexible and used many different ways.  Once you get it though you got it and learning more ways to bind will be simple.  I suggest learning exactly how the binding takes place so that you can manipulate and choose the best binding for any situation.